# Problem with timezone on iOS after timezone changes in Mexico

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, timezone

So, last year, the Mexican government decided to remove Daylight Savings time changes in Mexico. That means that for example part of the year Mexico City is -1 hours compared to New York and part of the year it's -2 hours compared to New York.

I know that iOS got a timezone update for that and it worked fine, you just had to confirm and restart your phone and it applies correctly.

The problem is that an app I am working on shows information on the user's timezone from the device itself. So what happens is have the following code:

```swift
import UIKit

class TimezoneController: BaseController {
    
    var timer = Timer()
    let dateInfo = DateFormatter()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var watchLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timezoneLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        var localTimeZoneAbbreviation: String {
            return TimeZone.current.abbreviation() ?? "N/D"
        }
        timezoneLabel.text = localTimeZoneAbbreviation
        
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateClock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
        dateInfo.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        dateInfo.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: localTimeZoneAbbreviation)
        
        updateClock()
    }
    
    @objc func updateClock()
    {
        let dateString = "\(dateInfo.string(from: Date() as Date))"
        watchLabel.text = String(dateString)
    }
    
}
```

I basically use the timer update to run the `updateClock()` function every second and update the text of my label.

So in theory the app gets the timezone from the device and displays the time according to that. But at the moment I get the following result:

- Timezone: CST
- Time in app: 18:52:58
- Device time: 17:52:58

Is this something that wasn't correctly patched in XCode or what do I need to do? In theory if the timezone were wrong it would show CDT, but it's showing CST.

**UPDATE**

I added the complete controller code.

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you tried `TimeZone.autoUpdatingCurrent` ?  Show the code for `updateClock`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine dude I literally put the entire code I am using for this... the only lines I did not put are the initialization of the timer and dateInfo objects and the viewDidLoad function which is where the code is located... What would be the minimal reproducible code for you in this case?

Comment: @Paulw11 I'll try it later today and let you know if it works, what's the difference about this property anyway?

Comment: This isn't an [mcve] because the code is just "floating", not shown in context. You haven't shown `updateClock` and there only seems to be one place where you set the timezone label, but you are expecting it to change.

Comment: Also show how you `print` the results you show, since `Date` do not have timezone, it is only when you print a date, that you can set a timezone. And as mentioned, minimal code in context that produces the output you show, including the `DateFormatters` you use to display them.

Comment: Ok, I added the complete controller code. Any recommendations now? You can remove the downvotes.

Comment: `Date() as Date` should simply be `Date()`. No need to cast a `Date` instance to a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is assuming that the timezone abbreviation "CST" represents a single, unique timezone. You rarely, if ever, want to create timezones using an abbreviation. Use timezone identifiers. Or in your case, just use the current local timezone.

Here's sample code that demonstrates your issue:

```swift
let tzMX = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Mexico_City")!
let tzCST = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CST")!
print(tzMX.identifier, tzMX.abbreviation(), tzMX.secondsFromGMT())
print(tzCST.identifier, tzCST.abbreviation(), tzCST.secondsFromGMT())
```

This outputs the following:

> America/Mexico_City Optional("CST") -21600
> America/Chicago Optional("CDT") -18000

`txMX` would be the actual local timezone on someone's device if they were in that part of Mexico. Your app is using a timezone that is the same as `tzCST`. That is why your app's clock is one hour off from the device's clock. You are using the wrong timezone. In the winter, your app would happen to show the correct time since Chicago would be on the same time as Mexico City from November to March.

The simple fix for your code is to delete the following line:

```swift
dateInfo.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: localTimeZoneAbbreviation)
```

That should be the only change. The date formatter will default to the local timezone. No need to set it.

Your code to show the current timezone abbreviation in a label is just fine. Just don't use the abbreviation to create a new timezone.

---

Unrelated but I suggest you also avoid using `dateFormat` to show a user the date and/or time. Use a style. In this case, `timeStyle`.

```swift
dateInfo.timeStyle = .medium
dateInfo.dateStyle = .none
```

This has the advantage of showing the user the time in the typical style they normally see. Not everyone expects the time in HH:mm:ss format.

Comment: Ok, @HangarRash in my case I obtain the zone that's active on the user's phone. So you're saying that if I remove the abbreviation line it would always show what's on the user's phone?

Comment: Yes, by default a date formatter uses the device's current timezone. That's why I said you need to delete the line where you set the wrong timezone.